# Exporting millions of records to excel using Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, code-first

I am developing a project in which millions of records need to be fetched from database and displayed in excel. I am unable to find an easy way to do this. First linq query takes a lot of time to fetch records from database, secondly binding to excel takes more time.

Some suggested to use indexing but there wasn't an easy way to add indexes in entity framework. Not much help on internet is available. If anyone can help me in doing this job, it will be highly appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
List<FarmerDetailsReport> fdr = (from fp in RptdataAccess.MST_FarmerProfile
     join pd in RptdataAccess.PersonalDetails on fp.personDetails.Id equals pd.Id
     join ic in RptdataAccess.IdentityCertificateDetails on fp.identityCertificate.Id equals ic.Id
     join pid in RptdataAccess.PacsInsuranceData on fp.pacsInsuranceData.Id equals pid.Id into temp
     from pid in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join bd in RptdataAccess.BankDetails on fp.bankDetails.Id equals bd.Id
     join cd in RptdataAccess.ContactDetails on fp.contactDetails.Id equals cd.Id
     join id in RptdataAccess.IncomeDetails on fp.incomeDetails.Id equals id.Id into tmp
     from id in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join ua in RptdataAccess.UserAttributes on fp.UserId equals ua.EmailID

     where ((user == "Administrator" || 
            ua.CompanyName == companyName || 
            ua.PACS == companyName) 
            && (
                cd.District == model.DistrictForProfileMIS || 
                model.DistrictForProfileMIS == null
                ) 
            && (
                cd.Block == model.BlockForProfileMIS || 
                model.BlockForProfileMIS == null || 
                model.BlockForProfileMIS == "Select"
                ) 
            && (
                bd.bankName == model.BankForProfileMIS || 
                model.BankForProfileMIS == null
                ) 
            && (
                ua.UserType == model.UserTypeForProfileMIS || 
                model.UserTypeForProfileMIS == null
                ) 
            && (
                ua.CompanyName == model.CompanyNameForProfileMIS || 
                model.CompanyNameForProfileMIS == null || 
                model.CompanyNameForProfileMIS == "Select") 
            && (
                (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(fp.CreatedOn) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(model.FromDate) 
                    && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(fp.CreatedOn) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(model.ToDate)) 
                     || (model.FromDate == null && model.ToDate == null)
                ) 
            && fp.Status == "Active")

     select new FarmerDetailsReport
     {
         FarmerURNNo = fp.URN_No,
         CreatedBy = fp.UserId,
         InsurerOrPACSName = ua.UserType == "Insurer" ? ua.CompanyName : ua.UserType == "PACs" ? ua.PACS : " ",
         CreatedOn = fp.CreatedOn,
         FarmerName = pd.FarmersName,
         FatherOrHusbandName = pd.FatherHusbandName,
         DateofBirth = pd.DateOfBirth,
         Gender = pd.IsMale.ToLower() == "yes" ? "Male" : "Female",
         MaritalStatus = pd.MaritalStatus,
         Religion = pd.Religion.ToLower() == "other" ? pd.otherReligion : pd.Religion,
         ReservationCategory = pd.ReservationCategory.ToLower() == "other" ? pd.otherReservationCategory : pd.ReservationCategory,
         IdentityCertificateType = ic.TypeOfCertificate.ToLower() == "other" ? ic.OtherIDType : ic.TypeOfCertificate,
         IdentityNumber = ic.IdentityNumber,
         DateofIssueIdentityNumber = ic.DateOfIssue,
         DistrictIdentityNumber = pid.DistrictId,
         Block = pid.Block,
         PACS = pid.PACS,
         PACSRegistrationNo = pid.PacsRegistrationNumber,
         PACSRegistrationDate = pid.PacsRegistrationDate,
         MembershipNo = pid.MembershipNo,
         DateofIssueMembershipNo = pid.DateOfIssue,
         TypeofBank = bd.bankType,
         BankName = bd.bankName,
         BranchName = bd.branchName,
         IFSCCodeNo = bd.iFSC_RTGSCode,
         BankAccountNo = bd.bankAccountNo,
         AccountType = bd.accountType.ToLower() == "other" ? bd.otherAccountType : bd.accountType,
         Address1 = cd.Address1,
         Address2 = cd.Address2,
         Address3 = cd.Address3,
         Circle = cd.Circle,
         State = cd.State,
         District = cd.District,
         Block_ = cd.Block,
         Pincode = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cd.Pincode),
         PhoneNoWithSTDCode = (cd.STDCODE == null ? "" : cd.STDCODE) + (cd.PhoneNumber == null ? "" : cd.PhoneNumber),
         Mobile = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cd.MobileNumber),
         Email = cd.Email,
         IncomeLevel = id.IncomeLevel,
         GrossfamilyIncome = id == null ? " " : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)id.GrossAnnualIncome),
         IncomecertificateIssuedBy = id.IncomeCertificateIssuedBy,
         CertificateNo = id == null ? " " : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)id.CertificateNo),
         CertificateDate = id.IssuedDate
.ToList();
```

Comment: "a lot of time" and "more time" are rather subjective. What did you measure and how did it compare to what you expect? Millions of lines won't be finished within seconds.

Comment: I don't think Excel can _handle_ that many rows.

Comment: Good point, Excel can handle up to 2^16 (65,536) rows per worksheet.

Comment: @gunr2171 If you split it out into multiple sheets you can. Use a stored procedure that exports to excel. Much faster and less complex

Comment: @Saket I'll keep an eye on this question. I tried doing the same thing and could not, and still used LINQ and OpenXml to mount excel file. For every hundred thousand records took 20 minutes. Records was distributed in a matrix of 22 X 350 within 14 spreadsheets.

Comment: My website is on azure server, before it binds to excel, 502 server error is shown. My query contains joins of 6 tables. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: @Shoe In my case I needed to use C # to be able to dynamically write the formulas in the spreadsheet cells because when Excel was open he needed to calculate values ​​dynamically.

Comment: @gunr2171 I am using Excel 2007, it can handle more than 65536 records. Earlier it used to show results when no of records in database were less. But now with 10 millions of records in database, complexity is largely increased.

Comment: If your question included code for what you've tried and specific amounts of time versus what you expected you wouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Okay, I am adding my code.

Comment: @Shoe, Time i already mentioned. After 5 mins, 502 web server takes place.

Comment: @Saket I was looking over your problem about 502 error and found this. Has this somehow related to your problem? http://forums.asp.net/t/1311835.aspx

Comment: Even if you could make it blazing fast, who could possibly make use of an Excel document populated with millions of records?

Comment: @Ocelot20, Leave about millions, not even 100,000 can be fetched and displayed.

Comment: If Excel is the final destination, wouldn't it be easier to use the data tools in excel to link directly to a VIEW?

Comment: -1 for a badly formatted irrelevant code block.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: Thanks for your -1. Would have thanked you more if you could be of any help instead of seeing a bad format.

Comment: You're not using the right tools here. For one, Entity framework is not suitable for handling that many rows, because materializing objects takes time and you are very likely to get out of memory exceptions, unless you split it up in batches (`Skip/Take`). And Excel is not the right application to contain and view these numbers of rows. What is the bigger picture here? Why is this necessary? I think you need a completely different approach, e.g. Sql Server Replication. As for the downvote, format the code well and its gone. Ill-formatted code strongly discourages others to help you.

Comment: Use a reporting tool like Sql Server Reporting Services. It is much more well suited to this use case and supports export to a number of formats, Excel included (though you'll need to make sure Excel 64bit is used by your customers)